# How to add a temp table in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I am trying to add a temp table to my query so that I can query that temp table, I have searched the internet but I couldn't get a solution.
this is my query

```
;WITH cte AS (
        SELECT ID, g.Name
        FROM game.Game g WITH(NOLOCK
        WHERE ID IN (SELECT Data FROM system.Split(1, ','))
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT g.ID,  g.Name
        FROM game.Game g WITH(NOLOCK) 
            JOIN cte ON g.ParentID = cte.ID
    )

    SELECT  c.ID,
        c.Name

    FROM cte c
        INNER JOIN list.Type gt WITH(NOLOCK) ON c.TypeId = gt.TypeID

    WHERE c.ID NOT IN (SELECT Data FROM system.Split(1, ','))
        AND c.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM game.code WITH(NOLOCK)
        WHERE ID = c.ID
            AND StatusCode IN ('OP', 'CL', 'SU')
            AND isDisplay = 'True' 
            AND GETDATE() BETWEEN DisplayStart AND DisplayEnd
            AND GETDATE() < ISNULL(ResultDateTime, ResultExpected) 
        )
```

which gives me the following when I run it

```
ID    | Name
1111  | BaseBall
2222  |BasketBall
45896 |Relay
```

now I tried to create a temp table as follows

```
Create Table #temp(
        ID int,
        Name varchar
        )
        ;WITH cte AS (
        SELECT ID, g.Name
        FROM game.Game g WITH(NOLOCK)
        WHERE ID IN (SELECT Data FROM system.Split(1, ','))
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT g.ID,  g.Name
        FROM game.Game g WITH(NOLOCK) 
            JOIN cte ON g.ParentID = cte.ID
    )
    insert into #temp  // i wanted to set these values in the temp table
    SELECT  c.ID,
        c.Name

    FROM cte c
        INNER JOIN list.Type gt WITH(NOLOCK) ON c.TypeId = gt.TypeID

    WHERE c.ID NOT IN (SELECT Data FROM system.Split(1, ','))
        AND c.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM game.code WITH(NOLOCK)
        WHERE ID = c.ID
            AND StatusCode IN ('OP', 'CL', 'SU')
            AND isDisplay = 'True' 
            AND GETDATE() BETWEEN DisplayStart AND DisplayEnd
            AND GETDATE() < ISNULL(ResultDateTime, ResultExpected) 
        )
```

every time I try to store this information in the temp table it gives me an error 'Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.' But I only have two values in. What am I doing wrong that I cant see?

Comment: Why are you using `NOLOCK`?

Comment: What is length of varchar column in Temp table u have given ?

Comment: To expand and @Larnu's comment...https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ And do you have a column named 1? That split function looks pretty suspect to me.

Answer (score 2):

First, why not just use `select into`?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#temp') IS NOT NULL  
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #temp
END
select c.ID, c.Name
into #temp
from . . .
```

Then you don't need to define `#temp` as a table.

Next, your definition is bad, because `Name` has only one character.  This would be fixed with `select into`.

However, I don't know why you are getting the particular error you are getting.  The numbers of columns appears to match.

Comment: Be aware while executing this as in same session it will throw error.